# Error en un bucle FOR, manejo de ficheros - PYTHON. Porque no añade bien los elementos?

Tags: python, python-3.7, archivo

Estoy intentando instanciar diferentes objetos y pasarlos a una lista, leyendo los atributos desde un fichero externo.(Son datos de persona: ID, nombre, apellido, fecha nacimiento)

Pero no comprendo el porque en mi lista de resultado no obtengo una lista con todas las personas de la lista y sus resultados, si se ejecuta deja 4 objetos iguales, como si corriera el bucle mas veces de las debidas.

Si corréis el programa que os dejo a continuación podréis ver el resultado que os quiero explicar

Muchas gracias por adelantado

```
class Persona:

atributos={
    'id':'',
    'nombre':'',
    'apellido':'',
    'nacimiento':'',
}

def __init__(self,to_id,to_nombre,to_apellido,to_nacimiento):
    self.atributos['id']=to_id
    self.atributos['nombre']=to_nombre
    self.atributos['apellido']=to_apellido
    self.atributos['nacimiento']=to_nacimiento
    
    
def __str__(self):
    retorno_id='(id='+self.atributos['id'] +')'
    retorno_nombre=self.atributos['nombre']+' '
    retorno_apellido=self.atributos['apellido']+' => '
    retorno_nacimiento=self.atributos['nacimiento']
    return retorno_id+retorno_nombre+retorno_apellido+retorno_nacimiento
    
    
    
personas=[]  

with open("personas.txt","r",encoding="utf8") as fichero:
    for linea in fichero:
        linea_listada=linea.split(';')
        personas.append(Persona(linea_listada[0],linea_listada[1],linea_listada[2],linea_listada[3]))

for i in personas:
    print(i)
```

#################
EN EL FICHERO EXTERNO
#################

```
1;Carlos;Pérez;05/01/1989
2;Manuel;Heredia;26/12/1973
3;Rosa;Campos;12/06/1961
4;David;García;25/07/2006
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal como está declarado, `atributos` es un **variable de clase**, es decir, es un sólo diccionario compartido por todas las instancias de la clase Persona. En consecuencia, el diccionario retiene el contenido de la última línea leida.

Lo que necesitas es un diccionario que sea un **variable de instancia**, o sea, un diccionario particular para cada instancia de Persona.

La definición correcta sería:

```
class Persona:
    def __init__(self, to_id, to_nombre, to_apellido, to_nacimiento):
        self.atributos = dict()
        self.atributos['id'] = to_id
        self.atributos['nombre'] = to_nombre
        self.atributos['apellido'] = to_apellido
        self.atributos['nacimiento'] = to_nacimiento
```

Aunque en realidad no necesitas un diccionario; basta con variables simples, asi:

```
class Persona:
    def __init__(self, to_id, to_nombre, to_apellido, to_nacimiento):
        self.id = to_id
        self.nombre = to_nombre
        self.apellido = to_apellido
        self.nacimiento = to_nacimiento
```

Por supuesto, también debes modificar el resto de la clase.

Comment: Vaaale vale, tienes toda la razón, error de principiante. Muchisimas gracias